# Detect Column containing special characters other than space - Postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I need to find the values from a text column which have characters other than *alphabets*, *numbers*, and *SPACE* (It is a name column so having space is allowed).

I am trying this which is not working

```
select * from table where name ~ '[^a-z0-9 ]';
```

I have left a space between 9 and ]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct regular expression would be:

```
[^[:alnum:] ]
```

That will match any string that contains a character that is neither alphabetical nor numerical nor space.

Comment: Thanks. How do I extend this expression to allow some other characters? Like hyphen, apostrophe, etc. I tried something like this but it doesnt seem to work  _name ~ '[^[:alnum:] -'']'_

Comment: The hyphen has to be the first character after the `^`, other than that it should work.

Comment: Great, works like magic! Would you be kind to explain why putting the hyphen as the first character works rather than adding it at the end?

Comment: Sure. A hyphen in the middle of a bracket list means a range, e.g. `[A-Z]` means all letters between `A` and `Z`. Only in the first position it does not have that meaning.

Comment: Ah, yes I get it! Thanks so much. Sometimes POSIX expressions are confusing. I long believed **^** is used to indicate the start of the string but looks like when put outside the **[]**, it acts as a negate. While we can simply use **!~** to search for NOT LIKE, why do **^** has a negate meaning as well?? Strange

Comment: `a ~ '[^x]'` is different from `a !~ '[x]'`.

Answer (score -1):

Try `^[-a-z0-9 ]`

I think you can use `\\w` instead of a-z0-9
so that looks like : `[-\\w.]`

Comment: Thank you. Using the ^ before the brackets seems to have worked. Can you kindly state how to exactly use the \w (in a complete expression). Because what you have stated above doesnt work.

Comment: That regexp is wrong. It matches `-`, a lower case ASCII character, digit or space *anchored at the beginning of the string*.